# Embedded SVG paths onclick get id

Tags: javascript, dom, svg

I'm trying to store the id of a clicked path of a SVG file inserted as object into the HTML document but I can't get it and still don't understand the problem.

I would like to end up with a clickable map divided in areas that will display some data (in the div#data) depending on the clicked zone. The data could be retrieved from a xml file.

Maybe there is a simpler approach to get this done.
Please, could I get some help?

Thanks

PARTIAL SVG CODE:

```
<defs>...
    <style>
        ...
    </style>
</defs>
<title>title here</title>
<g id="group1">
    <path id="zone1" onClick="selected(this.id)"  d="M482.56,0l-2,7a26.85,26.85,0,0,1-.79,4.26,20.67,20.67,0,0,0-.21,3.7,16.67,16.67,0,0,1-3.38,7.38c-1,1.48-.89,3.27-2.54,4.18-.9.5-.89,2.27-1.74,3.23-2.6,2.91-4.88,3.6-8.68,3-2.41-.39-4,2...
```

HTML CODE:

```
<article id="map">
    <object id="svg" type="image/svg+xml" data="images/mapa.svg">Your browser does not support SVG</object>
    <div id="result">
        <h3>header</h3>
        <div id="data" class="data"></div>
    </div>
</article>
```

JS CODE :

```
function selected(clicked_id){
     alert(clicked_id);
};
```

Why this script is not showing the id?

Comment: Why do you have to use your map in an object? Can you use it as inline SVG?

Comment: Hello Enxaneta, I try to get the HTML clean and easy to mantain and the svg is so long that makes it messy.

Comment: In this case you should put in an object (or maybe an image) only that part you don't need to change or manipulate, leaving the part you need to change as an inline SVG. I would recommend reading this article: [Optimizing SVG Text & Image Delivery with Inline SVG](https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/optimizing-svg-delivery-with-svg/)

Comment: Thank you, again. I just read the article which is great but I still don't get how to extract the paths. In the article she puts the text out of the drawings but my SVG more or less has only paths.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your logic and it worked for me. However, one difference is that the snippet contains the SVG DOM entirely. I don't know if Stackoverflow supports uploading separate files to be used as external SVG.

In my snippet I used jQuery to attach click events to SVG paths.

```js
$(".heart").click(function(){
  var color = $(this).attr("fill");
  console.log(color,"clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Click a heart!</h1>
<svg width="200" height="100" style="background-color: #bada55" >
  <g transform="scale(1.2)">
    <path class="heart" d="M 10,30 A 20,20 0,0,1 50,30 A 20,20 0,0,1 90,30 Q 90,60 50,90 Q 10,60 10,30 z" fill="red"></path>
  </g>
  
  <g transform="scale(0.8) translate(140,40)">
    <path class="heart" d="M 10,30 A 20,20 0,0,1 50,30 A 20,20 0,0,1 90,30 Q 90,60 50,90 Q 10,60 10,30 z" fill="black"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Ahmad,thanks for your reply but, as I answered to Exaneta, I want my svg external because is huge.